# Problema de instalación de flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Uso Linux Mint 18.3 que solo tenía hasta python 3.5, he intalado y compilado la versión 3.7.7 y la 3.8.2

He creado un entorno virtual:

```
python3.7 -m venv venv
```

Dentro instalo sin problema flask mediante pip

Pero al instalar flask-sqlalchemy da un error y se interrumpe. Solo he podido instalarlo en la versión de python 3.5

Os dejo el error por si me podéis ayudar:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 331, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 516, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req, self.req_tracker, self.finder, self.build_isolation,
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 95, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 38, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._setup_isolation(finder)
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 96, in _setup_isolation
    reqs = backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 152, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    'config_settings': config_settings
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 255, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mi_usuario/flask-project/plinic/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 63, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t6131_zw/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t6131_zw/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 33, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-t6131_zw/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Comment: Hola, instala [libffi-dev](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libffi-dev) si no la tienes instalada. (`sudo apt-get install libffi-deb`) y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias. No encuentra el paquete: `Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete libffi-deb`

Comment: Argggg tenía un typo, perdona, debería ser `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` (tenía una `b` en vez de una `v` en `dev`....)

Comment: No ha funcionado. Finalmente he instalado un docker con python:3.6-alpnine y un volumen compartido para crear venv y listo.